# Writing a stored procedure with an insert statement with unlimited parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm having a bit of trouble with a question given to me in an assignment. My lecturer isn't the greatest at explaining things in a way I can understand, so I'm hoping I can get some help here.

This is the question we were given:

> Construct a stored procedure to insert data into the keyword table. The format of the input string should be (Topic_name, ‘K1,W1,K2,W2,K3,W3…Kn, Wn’). Ks are keywords and Ws are weights. If the Topic name cannot be found in the Topic table then you need to insert the new topic name into the Topic table first and subsequently insert other data into the keyword table. Your stored procedure should always check the string pattern to ensure it is correctly formatted and the correct data types are used. Provide a feedback message to the user if the string pattern is invalid.

This is my keyword table:

```
CREATE TABLE Keyword(
    Topic_Name  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Keyword VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    K_weight    INT     NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Topic_Name, Keyword),
    FOREIGN KEY(Topic_Name) REFERENCES Topic);
```

The main issue I'm having is with the parameters. I have no idea how to get the SP to count how many parameters the user has included. Any help I could get would be greatly appreciated. If you need any additional information, just let me know. Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a variable number of parameters to a SQL Server stored procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485526/how-to-pass-a-variable-number-of-parameters-to-a-sql-server-stored-procedure)

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: When you hand your assignment in, make sure you ask your lecturer why you're using a *string* to pass this data, instead of something more appropriate, such as [Table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) (or even XML would probably be better, since you could validate its schema)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you started. It parses a comma separated list of values into a temporary table:

```
DECLARE @KeywordList varchar(max) //This can be a SP param

CREATE TABLE #Keywords(varchar(10) keyword NOT NULL); 

DECLARE @Keyword varchar(10), @Pos int

SET @KeywordList= LTRIM(RTRIM(@KeywordList))+ ','
SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @KeywordList, 1)

--Parse varchar and split IDs by comma into temp table
IF REPLACE(@KeywordList, ',', '') <> ''
BEGIN
    WHILE @Pos > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Keyword= LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@KeywordList, @Pos - 1)))
        IF @Keyword <> ''
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Keywords(ID) VALUES (@Keyword) 
        END
        SET @KeywordList = RIGHT(@KeywordList, LEN(@KeywordList) - @Pos)
        SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @KeywordList, 1)

    END
END 

--Return a count of all rows
SELECT @TotalRows = COUNT(Keyword) FROM #Keywords; 

    --Now process data from #Keywords as required
```

Comment: Ended up using a variation of this, adding in an ID column to make things easier for myself. Now to figure out how to modify the temporary table to insert the information into the Keyword table! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, your procedure will have just one string parameter. You then parse this string inside stored procedure (look for commas) and process each parameter till the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can to use temporary tables as below.

Procedure which expects "array":

```
create table #array
(
  value1 varchar(30),
  value2 varchar(30)
)
go

create procedure myproc
as
begin

  select * from #array

end
go

drop table #array

go
```

Procedure fill and send an array to myproc:

```
create procedure myproc2
as
begin

  create table #array
  (
    value1 varchar(30),
    value2 varchar(30)
   )
  --fill an array             
  insert into  #array values ('A','B')      
  insert into  #array values ('C','D')

  exec myproc

  drop table #array
end

go
```

and you can run it:

```
exec myproc2
```